# Combine/Nest/Implement Stack Navigator and Tab Navigator React Navigation components for React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to make a Water Tracker app (I know that already exists, I only want to challenge myself because this is my first project) and I want to use the Stack Navigator (That is already in the app) with the Tab Navigator. I've tried a lot of solution from Medium, Stackoverflow and official React Navigation documentation but none of them works for me. My goal is to have both stack navigator and  tab navigator in all the screens. I'm using Expo CLi.
This is the source code:
https://snack.expo.io/XDRjrC7Gf
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? your code does not have a tab navigator, its easy for us to help if you can explain your requirement

Comment: @Guruparan Giritharan, my goal is to have both stack and tab navigator in all pages

Comment: You cant do that, you can have tabs inside stack or vise versa, if your tab is just a set of buttons to navigate you can create a custom component

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: If it's not possible, is there a way to make something that looks like a stack navigator component? Like a header for the screens (supporting safe area view).

Comment: You can make a header component and place it on top, but if you have a requirement to show the tab name it will involve some work